# How to reuse the same implementation method for diferent classes

Tags: c++, class, optimization, reusability

I'm practicing c++ and I got stuck on the following codes trying to optimize them. I'd like to know if there is something I can do to optimize their method's implementation. Because the methods are the same except for the consts. Thanks in advance.

dominios.h

```
class HP {
private:

  int valor;

  static const int LIMITE_INFERIOR = 0;
  static const int LIMITE_SUPERIOR = 1000;

public:

  void setValor(int);
  int getValor() {
    return valor;
  }
};

class MP {
private:

  int valor;

  static const int LIMITE_INFERIOR = 0;
  static const int LIMITE_SUPERIOR = 500;

public:

  void setValor(int);
  int getValor() {
    return valor;
  }
};
```

dominios.cpp

```
void HP::setValor(int valor) {

  if (valor < LIMITE_INFERIOR) this->valor = LIMITE_INFERIOR;
  else if (valor > LIMITE_SUPERIOR) this->valor = LIMITE_SUPERIOR;
  else this->valor = valor;
}

void MP::setValor(int valor) {

  if (valor < LIMITE_INFERIOR) this->valor = LIMITE_INFERIOR;
  else if (valor > LIMITE_SUPERIOR) this->valor = LIMITE_SUPERIOR;
  else this->valor = valor;
}
```

As you can see the setValor of both classes are the same. I tried to do hierarchy using a "template" but that didn't work for me because of the consts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this->valor = std::clamp(valor, LIMITE_INFERIOR, LIMITE_SUPERIOR);
```

---

```
template <typename Tag, int lo, int hi>
class Metric {
private:
  int valor;

public:
  void setValor(int v) { valor = std::clamp(v, lo, hi); }
  int getValor() { return valor; }
};

struct HPTag;
using HP = Metric<HPTag, 0, 1000>;

struct MPTag;
using MP = Metric<MPTag, 0, 500>;
```

Comment: oh, thanks! Do you also know what could I do to avoid writing the implementation of setValor twice? As the implementation are the same, except for the consts?

Comment: Updated the answer with one possible approach.

Comment: Hey, one more question, why the use of structs above?

Comment: The tags? They may or may not be necessary, depending on the rest of your design. They allow you to create two distinct types of metrics, even if they happen to have the same boundaries. So that, for example, you can overload functions on them.

Comment: I think I understood, but shouldn't it be class instead of struct than?

Comment: Using the metric like that is like as you were merging the struct with the class and creating a "new type"?

Comment: Imagine you have `template  <typename T> class C{};` Then `C<SomeType>` and `C<SomeOtherType>` are two distinct types - you could, for example, have two overloaded functions `void f(C<SomeType>)` and `void f(C<SomeOtherType>)`. This is true even if `C` doesn't actually use `T` anywhere in its definition; and in fact, `SomeType` and `SomeOtherType` don't even need to be defined, it's sufficient to merely declare them. Whether they are declared as `struct` or `class` doesn't make any difference.